# How to use proguard with data binding (proguard.ParseException in aapt_rules.txt)?

Tags: android, proguard, android-databinding

I enabled proguard for my project and got the following error:

```
01:25:13.221 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '(' or separator ';' before '{' in line 147 of file '/blalblah/proguard-rules/release/aapt_rules.txt'
```

The mentioned line indeed looks funny:

```
# onClick res/layout/host_entry.xml #generated:35
-keepclassmembers class * { *** ${()->cb.onDeleteClicked(host)}(...); }
```

Which looks like some copypaste from my layout:

```
        <ImageButton
        ....
        android:onClick="${()->cb.onDeleteClicked(host)}" />
```

So some proguard config generator thinks that only some method name can specified as `onClick` value and just puts the expression to the proguard config.

Is it possible to make it work without getting rid of nice lambda onclick handlers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AAPT behaves correctly here. It is configured to ignore databinding expression values for the Proguard config generation. But yours is not a databinding expression:

```
android:onClick="${()->cb.onDeleteClicked(host)}"
```

Instead you have to use `@{}`:

```
android:onClick="@{()->cb.onDeleteClicked(host)}"
```

`${}` is an unsupported shell expression.